# How to pass parameters in a MSXML2.xmlhttp POST?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, post, xmlhttprequest, msxml

I do not know how to send a request to a website, with a parameter set to a specific value, using MSXML2.xmlhttp.

**Edit as suggested**:

SSlinky in the comments states my trial is technically correct, that's why I want to show a more pertinent example.

I succeed to get the home page of the site.

```vb
    myURL = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/translate/"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlhttp.send
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
    Set form = html.getElementsByClassName("clrd nocontain")(0)
    action = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/translate/"
```

Then collect all hidden inputs

```vb
    Set inputList = form.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each hiddenInput In inputList
        If InStr(hiddenInput.outerHTML, "hidden") Then
            If querystring = "" Then
                querystring = hiddenInput.getAttribute("name") & "=" & hiddenInput.getAttribute("value")
            Else
                querystring = querystring & "&" & hiddenInput.getAttribute("name") & "=" & hiddenInput.getAttribute("value")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Then I add the specific input value, and call the POST

```
body = "txtTrans=dog&" & querystring
Call xmlhttp.Open("POST", action, False)
Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Call xmlhttp.send(body)
If xmlhttp.Status <> 200 Then Exit Sub
html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

I would expect I find the following result into the `responseText`

```
<div id="translate-tool__result" class="tc-bb translate-tool__result translate-english-spanish js-translator-result" lang="it">
                                    cane
                                            </div>
```

Instead I find

```
<div class="tc-bb translate-tool__result translate-english-spanish js-translator-result" id="translate-tool__result">
                                        </div>
```

with no result.

**Previous Question**:

I simulated my problem with the example below, where I assign the value "dog" to the input "si". The `action` is taken from the `form`.

```
<input type="text" name="w" id="si" oninvalid="alert('Caratteri non validi nella casella di ricerca');" pattern="^[^<>%\\]*$" size="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="1" onkeydown="keyDown(event)" accesskey="s" title="accesskey: s" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none">
```

```
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim action As String
Dim body As Variant

    action = "https://www.wordreference.com/redirect/translation.aspx"
    body = "si=dog"
    Call xmlhttp.Open("POST", action, False)
    Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Call xmlhttp.send(body)
    If xmlhttp.Status <> 200 Then Exit Sub
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
    
    Debug.Print html.getElementsByClassName("ToWrd").Length
```

Into the response I do not get the `<TD>` below (`.length` is always 0), that is meant to contain the result of the request, that I get if I interact by the web.

`<td class="ToWrd">cane <em class="POS2 tooltip" data-lang="it" data-loaded="true">nm<span><i>sostantivo maschile</i>: Identifica un essere, un oggetto o un concetto che assume genere maschile: <b>medico, gatto, strumento, assegno, dolore</b> </span></em><i class="copy"></i></td>`

What am I missing here?

Comment: That site doesn't seem to take a POST. The form triggers a GET, e.g. `https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/hello%2C world!`

Comment: Thank you @SSlinky, my bad: I took a wrong example. Actually my problem was on another [site](https://www.registroimprese.it/home), accepting a post, cause the form tag is like `<form action="https://www.registroimprese.it/home?p_auth=HHI6P7Jm&amp;p_p_id=1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_id=column-2&amp;p_p_col_count=1&amp;_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_javax.portlet.action=cerca" class="form  " id="_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_searchForm" method="post" name="_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_searchForm">`
I wonder how to pass POST parameters.

Comment: **What you're doing is technically correct.** That site sends recaptcha information. It also sends two POSTS and a GET, not just reading the response from a single POST. I'd put this one solidly in the 'too hard basket'. Edit for clarity.

Comment: Thank you @SSlinky, I edited as suggested with a more pertinent example. Does the 'too hard' basket exist for real? Do you think there are any websites not accepting POST requests sent by software?

Comment: Moreover, if I guess correctly, the MSXML2.xmlhttp POST shouldn't be affected by the recaptcha prompt, as it only blocks the front-end, doesn't it?